# Are there any ARM based systems/emulators with a graphical frame buffer that allow for (relatively) legacy-free Assembly programming?

Tags: arm, assembly, framebuffer

I am looking for a modern system to do some bare bones Assembly programming (for fun/learning) that does not have the legacy burden of x86 platforms (where you still have to deal with BIOS, switching to protected mode, VESA horrors to be able to output pixels to the screen in modern resolutions/colordepths etc.). Do such systems even exist? I suspect it is not even possible today to do low-level graphics programming without dealing with proprietary hardware.

Comment: If you don't want to deal with a lot of nonsense, 64-bit x86 assembly is actually quite reasonable. The calling conventions are pretty standardized, so using kernel system calls and C libraries is straightforward enough, and quite a bit of legacy cruft is gone. Besides, the difference between accessing hardware video memory through a library like SDL and setting up the hardware directly really is just learning the hardware quirks and specs vs learning a library interface. The code that actually deals with pixels will look the same regardless of how you got access to them.

Comment: That said, a virtual ARM computer with straightforward, modern hardware designed for assembly language programming would be fun as hell, so I upvoted your question.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I just miss the old days ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

qemu is likely what you want if you dont want to have to build that stuff in.  You wont get as much visibility as to what is going on in the guts of it.

For hardware, beagleboard (dont get the old one get the new one with reasonable connectors, etc), or the open-rd board.  I was disappointed with the plug computer thing.  The hawkboard I like better than the beagleboard, but am concerned about the big banner about a pcb design problem.  The raspberry pi will be out at some point and will also provide what you are looking for.  Note that for beagleboard, etc, you dont have to run linux or anything like that, you can write your own binary and xmodem it over or use the network and then just run it, not a problem at all.

The stellaris eval boards all/most have oled displays, monochrome and small but graphics, not sure how much you were after.

earth-lcd used to have an arm based board with a decent sized panel on it.

there is of course the gameboy advance and the nintendo ds.  flash/developer cartridges are under $20.  the gba is better to start with IMO, as the nds is like two gbas competing for shared resources and a little confusing.  with a ez flash cartridge (open source software to program), was easy to put a bootloader on the gba and for like another $20 create a serial cable, I have a serial based bootloader for loading the programs.  If you have an interest in this path start with the visual boy advance emulator to get your feet wet and see how you feel about the platform.

If you go to sparkfun.com there are likely a number of boards that either already have lcd connectors that you would mate up with a display or definitely displays and breakout boards that you could connect to a number of microcontroller development boards.  Other than the insanely painful blue leds, and the implication that there is 64KB (there is but non-linear 32KB+16+16) the mbed board is nice, up to 100mhz, cortex-m3.  I have some mbed samples at github as well that walk you through building an arm binary too boot an arm from flash for those that have not done it (and want to learn that rather than call some apis in a sandbox).

the armmite pro and the maple (sparkfun) are arm based arduino footprint platforms, so for example you can get the color lcd shield or the gameduino

There is the open pandora project.  I was quite dissappointed with the experience, after over a year paid another fee to get the unit and it failed within a few minutes.  Sent it back and I need to check my credit card statement, maybe we took the return and give it to someone who wants it path.  I have used the gamepark gp32 and gpx2, but not the wiz, the gpx2 was fine other than some memory I/O problem in the chip that caused chaotic timing. the thing would run just fine but memory performance was all over the map and non-deterministic. the gp32 is not what you are looking for but the gpx2 might be, finding connectors for a serial cable might be more difficult now that the cell phone cable folks used to cut up is not as readily available.

gen 1 ipod nanos can still be had easily, as well as the older gen ipod classics.  easy to homebrew, the lcd panels are easy to get at.  grayscale only, maybe only black and white I dont remember.  All the programming info is had from the ipodlinux folks.

I have not tried it yet but the barns and noble folks are homebrew friendly or as friendly as anyone on that scale has been so far.  the nook color can easily be turned into a generic android device, so I assume that also means you could develop homebrew on the metal, not sure though, have not studied it.

You might look at always innovating, my experience with them was similar to the open pandora folks.  These folks started with a modified beagleboard in a box with a display and batteries, then added a couple more products, any one of them should be very open, and homebrew friendly so you can write whatever level you want, boot and run on the metal, no problem.  For the original product it was one of those wait for several months things.

I am hoping the raspberry pi becomes the next beagleboard but better.

BTW all hardware is proprietary, it is just a matter of whether they choose to provide programming information or not.  vesa came about because no two vendors did it the same way, and that has not changed, you have to still read the dataseets and programmers reference manuals.   But as you can see above I have only scratched the surface, and covered the sub or close to $100 items.  If you are willing to pay in the thousands of dollars that greatly opens the door to graphics based development platforms that are well documented and relatively sandbox free.  many are arm based since arm is the choice for phones, etc and these are phone-like, tablet-like, eval platforms.

Comment: My Open Pandora experience has been much better.  I recommend Open Pandora or any ARM Linux device, and to use the Linux framebuffer /dev/fb which will hide the hardware for you.  I'm not sure how difficult it would be to program the GPU / video directly, if you want to do it without the OS; perhaps quite difficult.  You could also use x68 Linux and /dev/fb.

Comment: Why are you removing references to your github from your answers?  In this case, I assume qemu is just as good, but why all of your other answers?

Comment: @PeterCordes Links are bad in answers, was time for a clean up, some of those sites I have not maintained or even know if they are up.  Should never have put the links in there in the first place.   A number of these questions now that I see them should have been closed for one or more reasons...Some selected ones of mine are very much in the primarily opinion based and the content of the answer is outdated, cant close selected ones...

Comment: @old_timer: I highly disagree that links are bad in answers in general.  Link *only* answers are bad, but mentioning useful tools or links for more info as part of a complete answer is totally fine.  If the code you were linking has been unmaintained for years, then yeah it makes sense to remove those mentions.

Comment: Adding links of any kind to answers requires constant maintenance and is discouraged.  the external links are not maintained by the stack exchange folks so the quality of the question and as pointed out how much of the answer centers around the link(s) is not contained within SO.  Just doing maintenance, didnt realize it was going to move all those questions forward in the active list pushing current stuff down the page...

Answer (score 1):

The Android emulator is such a beast; it runs a linux kernel and driver stack (including `/dev/fb`) that one can log into via the android debugger bridge, and run (statically linked) arm-linux-eabi applications. Framebuffer access is possible; see [example](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/ace258af92fff692?dmode=source&pli=1).

The meta-question rather is, what do you mean by "low-level" graphics programming; no emulator is going to expose all the register and chip state complexity that's behind a modern graphics chip pipeline. But simple framebuffer contents manipulation (pixel buffer access) is surely simple enough, as is experimenting with software rendering in ARM assembly.

Of course, things that you can do with the Android emulator you can also do with cheap physical ARM hardware, like the beagleboard and similar. Real complexity only begins when you want to access "advanced" things - that's anything accelerated functionality beyond just reading/writing framebuffer contents.

Comment: Actually I was looking for a way to do bare bones assembly programming (that is without an OS that provides a /dev/fb abstractions or anything like that). Think more like: http://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/14/simplest-bare-metal-program-for-arm/

Comment: Well, the Android emulator _is_ QEMU. It boots a Linux kernel (and before that some sort of bootloader), so you could theoretically create your own bootloader/kernel for it as well. Not that I know anyone who's done that (the kernel ok, but not lower than that, and also not "a kernel but not a modification of the Linux kernel"). For what you hope to achieve, physical hardware would probably be best.

Comment: In addition to that, the "`/dev/fb` abstraction" is one of the most useful / time-saving things when it comes to actually getting the screen switched on and configured (resolution / timings). Doing _that_ by directly programming a graphics chip's registers is significantly more complex than the "VESA horrors" you mention in your question.

Answer (score 1):

**New Answer**

I recently came across this while looking for emulators to run NetBSD on, but there's a project called [GXemul](http://gxemul.sourceforge.net/gxemul-stable/doc/intro.html#cpus) that provides a full-system computer architecture emulation with support for a variety of virtual devices and CPUs. The primary and most up-to-date core looks to be MIPS-based, but it also lists support for emulating the ARM architecture. It even includes an integrated debugger and it sounds like you can just assemble your code into a raw binary with some bootstrapping code and boot it as a kernel inside the emulator from the commandline.

**Previous Answer**

This isn't an emulator, but if you're interested in having a complete, ARM-based computer that you can develop whatever you want on that doesn't cost much, you should keep an eye on the [Raspberry Pi project](http://www.raspberrypi.org/). They're very close to selling a complete, tiny, low-power ARM-based computer for $25 a piece. It has USB ports, ethernet, video out, and an SD card reader, and can boot Linux, although in your case you'd probably want to boot your own code and access the hardware directly.

EDIT: Looks like Erik already mentioned it.